# Trying to Open a ".SH" Script with adb commands using JFileChoser

Tags: java, android, bash, terminal

I'm Created a tool using basic Java to help my testing of an android device a little faster. I am using Linux Ubuntu, trying to run .sh scripts. I created a little JFrame with some buttons, and one of the buttons opens up (JFileChoser) a folder and that works and all; but know I want to be able to select a script .sh file and make it run when I click on the "open" button. But I can't seem to make it work! so here is my code from the actionclass page. 
Remember I want to make the .sh script file run and be able to run the command on the .sh script itself. 
Any help is highly appreciated!!!

Code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;



public class adbScript extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private File runfile;
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {         
{

//Handle open button action.
JFileChooser("/home/local/ANT/arthm/Desktop/stuff"); 
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(".sh", "sh");
adbfile.setFileFilter(filter);

int returnVal = adbfile.showOpenDialog(null);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

runfile = adbfile.getSelectedFile();

//getPath()
try {
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(runfile.getParent());
}
catch (IOException e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e1.printStackTrace();
}
//This is where a real application would open the file.
System.out.println("File: " + runfile.getName() + ".");    
} else {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Open command cancelled by user.");
}
System.out.println(returnVal);
   }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this line:

```
runfile = adbfile.getSelectedFile(); // good
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(runfile.getParent());
// this will try to open your sh file's parent folder, it won't execute your sh file
```

It should be:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(runfile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: @user2367924 You're wellcome!! :D If this worked for you please don't forget to accept the answer, so people looking for similar problems can identify this as useful. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)